# Set font size for an entire page using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have this small HTML page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>
    <script>
        function myf () {
            var z = document.getElementById('no').value;
            var x = document.getElementById('p');

            l = parseInt(z);

            if ((l > 40) || (l < 10)) {
                alert('please enter a value between 10 to 40');
            }

            x.style.fontSize = l + "px";
        }
    </script>
    <body>
        <input type="button" onClick="myf();" value="resize"/>
        <input type="text" id="no"/>
        <p id="p" style="font-size:24px;">text here</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

And it changes the font size of the element with the id `p`, but I want it to change the font size for all the text on the page; even the ones not enclosed in a `p` tag. More exactly, I want it to do something like `*{}` does in CSS.

Comment: You want to change the font size of everything to the same thing? I can't see that being a good idea in most cases.

Comment: Yeah I know it,but I need to do it in my project!I want to change the font size for all the text on the page

Comment: Did you try wrapping everything you want to change in a `div`?

Comment: Is it a good idea if I specify an id for '<body>' and I do my changes on it??Is it possible?And excuse me for my grammatical mistakes

Comment: @progarmer79, Check [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29188414/865175) below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do that is by setting the `font-size` CSS property for the entire `<body>` element and removing the inline `font-size` of that `<p>` element. Something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>
    <script>
        function myf () {
            var z = document.getElementById('no').value;

            l = parseInt(z);

            if ((l > 40) || (l < 10)) {
                alert('please enter a value between 10 to 40');
            }

            document.body.style.fontSize = l + "px";
        }
    </script>
    <body>
        <input type="button" onClick="myf();" value="resize"/>
        <input type="text" id="no"/>
        <p id="p">text here</p>
        <span>another text here</span>
    </body>
</html>
```